# Using JavaScript with Angular Component: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have successfully managed to connect my external `JavaScript` file to my `angular` component, however it doesn't work in some instances.

I connected my `src/custom.js` file to my `app.component.html` through `angular.json`, as illustrated below:

```js
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],

"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
   "src/custom.js"
]
```

*Context:*
The demo script is a simple alert saying hello that pops every time I connect to my localhost. 
As far as I'm aware there's no issue with the external `js` file being referenced.

My issue seems to come from more complex functions.
[Here's the example that am trying to implement](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) from w3schools.

And it's set up as follows:

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

```js
// custom.js 

dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
     document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
     elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX; pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX; 
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX; 
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

> **Error: Cannot read property 'id' of null at dragElement (custom.js:13) at custom.js:6**

I have come across a similar error before.
My suspicion is that it has something to do with loading the `DOM` vs running the `js`?

Unfortunately I'm very new to `Angular`, with no experience in setting up basic web pages.

**Does anybody have any insight?**

Comment: p.s Using Angular 9

Comment: 1. you're calling your script before the div exists, so `document.getElementById("mydiv")` returns `null` 2. [do not use, let alone link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: Can you just define all these functions in the app.component.ts file? This way you wont need to add custom.js file to your project. Hint: use AfterViewInit for the element initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tag your DOM element using #someTag, then get it with @ViewChild('someTag').